# Regular Expression DateTime Javascript

Tags: regex, datetime

I need an expression which matches,DateTime format (DD/MM/YYYY),i've already found it.

However,it only works to (1/6/2009) or (1/5/2010),it doenst support (01/06/2009) or (01/05/2010).

How can i check if a string is a dateTime in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this nifty library : [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (which I found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy/datemmddyyyy.html)):

> `(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d`

In order to make this match dates without leading zeros on the month and the day you will need to change it up a bit:

> `(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d`

Comment: What about the other centuries? And the 31th of february?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library? It has no problem with those patterns.